# How to make Deep Links work normally in Angular 8 production build

Tags: typescript, angular8

I am creating a new angular application where I plot different graphs using plotly. Now the point is, the route is :abc/:xyz/:pqr. whenever I access localhost:4200/abc/xyz/pqr the appropriate graph is plotted in the dev mode, but in the production mode due to being a deep link, browser instead creates a request and it shows 404 Not found error. I want these deep links to work normally, like redirecting to component

I tried putting {useHash: true} it doesn't work.

Comment: You need to setup your production web server to correctly handle HTML 5 SPAs. `useHash` is an option, but only if you change all of your URLs.

Comment: You need to set up your server to serve an angular app. There are countless guides.

Comment: I'm a beginner, can you help me with the configuration, it is on flask